# Chromium policies: Differences in my PC and VM Ware

Tags: registry, chromium, policies

I am trying to set my default search engine in chromium browser by adding policies in registry (OS Windows 10). I set values in registry by *.reg file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Chromium]
"DefaultSearchProviderEnabled"=dword:00000001
"DefaultSearchProviderName"="My search"
"DefaultSearchProviderNewTabURL"="https://search.mysearch.com"
"DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL"="https://search.mysearch.com/search?gd=SY1001471&q={searchTerms}"
```

Everything is ok in my PC. But if I try to set these settings on virtual machine I get google as my default search engine. (I use VMWare Workstation 15 Pro. Win10 x64)

Why these settings do not work on virtual machine? What can be the reason of that behavior on VM?

Comment: These setting work if my PC is a part of domain. Is there are a way to change search engine for all PCs?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution on chromium forum: 
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!mydiscussions/chromium-dev/l5wbMgqSeDM